# D3 Choropleth Map: Colors are not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth

I am having issues with Choropleth Map using D3.

I want to show occurrences of disaster to the World Map for the given year, say 2015.

I have a dropdown to change disaster type. I am currently working with "Earthquake".

Before selecting "Earthquake" from dropdown:
[image]

After Selecting "Earthquake", it is changing colors, but somehow not changing as per the value. Below is the output:
[image]

**Below is my code to generate map, It is not showing any error as well.**

```
       // Load Data
        d3.csv("disaster_data.csv", function(data){
            // Set color
            color.domain([
                d3.min(data, function(d) { return +d[occurrence]; }), 
                d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d[occurrence]; })
            ]);

            // Load Map JSON
            d3.json("d3-geo/mapshaper_output.json", function(error, json) {
                if (error) throw error;
                // Create Map
                var countries = svg.selectAll(".countries")
                                       .data(json.features)
                                       .enter()
                                       .append("path");
                countries.attr("d", path)
                                   .attr("stroke", "gray");

                // Return number of occurrences for given dataset countrywise
                function get_occurrences(disaster_type, year){
                    if(disaster_type == "Earthquake"){
                        var dataEarthquake = data.filter(function(a) {return a.disaster_type == disaster_type});
                        var dataEarthquake_Year = dataEarthquake.filter(function(a) {return a.year == year});
                        for(var i = 0; i < dataEarthquake_Year.length; i++){
                            var dataCountryCode = dataEarthquake_Year[i].iso;
                            var dataOccurence = +dataEarthquake_Year[i].occurrence;
                            for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
                                var jsonCountryCode = json.features[j].properties.iso_a3;
                                if (dataCountryCode == jsonCountryCode) {
                                    json.features[j].properties.occurrence = dataOccurence;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }                   
                        }
                        countries.attr("d", path)
                                .attr("stroke", "gray")
                                .attr("fill", function(d) {
                            var value = d.properties[occurrence];
                                                            if (value) {
                                return color(value);
                            } else {
                                return "#aaa";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                // Dropdown change event
                dropdown.on("change", change);
                var selected_year = 2015;
                var occurrence_country = 0;

                function change(){
                    if(this.value == "Earthquake"){
                        occurrence_country = get_occurrences("Earthquake", selected_year);
                    }
                }
            }); // JSON ends
            d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
        }); // CSV Load ends
```

Can anyone please look into the code and help?

**EDITED:**
Adding code which used for color

```
var colorgrad = ['#fcfbfd','#efedf5','#dadaeb','#bcbddc','#9e9ac8','#807dba','#6a51a3','#54278f','#3f007d'];
var color = d3.scale.quantize().range(colorgrad);
```

Comment: `get_occurrences` is only called when the dropdown changes. Which might explain why the colors change only when you use the dropdown.

Comment: Yeah, but it should show any other color than gray for few countries, like there are some values in the data from India, China at least. They should be in another color

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
countries.attr("d", path)
    .attr("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        var value = d.properties[occurrence];
        if (value) {
            return color(value);
        } else {
            return "#aaa";
        }
    });
```

Try:

```
d3.selectAll("path)
    .attr("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        var value = d.properties[occurrence];
        if (value) {
            return color(value);
        } else {
            return "#aaa";
        }
    });
```

Comment: It says "undefined is not an object (evaluating d.properties)

Comment: json.features[j].properties.occurrence = dataOccurence; at this line, there are 12 entries in JSON. So it is not empty...

Comment: That's a problem, it has to be only 1.

Comment: I mean to say it has data for 12 countries like India, China etc.. so it should not show gray for all the countries... it is currently going in "else" part and not reading any "value" from the properties. Ideally, it should show different color for India, China and other 10 countries ...

Comment: Do a `console.log(value)` just before the `if` and tell me what you get.

Comment: It is giving me an error which I've mentioned above. But if I revert back to old code it is showing "undefined" coming up several time...

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(d)` before `value`?

Comment: It is also undefined. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128362/discussion-between-rajat-agarwal-and-gerardo-furtado).

Comment: This discussion has been moved to chat, hope you can come over there for more discussion... or do you want to discuss here? Also It is showing [object Object] if I run for old code...

Comment: No, I can't. To check why there is no bound data, the best idea is creating a plunker or a fiddle, so I can have a look.

Comment: Can I upload my csv file in plunker? I guess I cannot in Fiddle

Comment: You can do it in both of them.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Rmf8N4e91unuXglae6yO?p=preview here is the plunker. Please have a look

Comment: I'm only getting "bad request" with this plunker... I'll try again later.

Comment: Oh.. I am not sure what's wrong with it. Thanks @Gerardo.