# D3 Tooltip: Unable to get tooltip working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am unable to get tooltip working in my line chart. I have tweaked the code but sometimes it doesn't show me an error. Can somebody help me set up tooltips in my line chart?

Below is my CSS and complete JS code.

CSS:

```
div.tooltip {   
        position: absolute;         
        text-align: center;         
        white-space: normal;                    
        padding: 2px;               
        font-size: 14px;        
        background: whitesmoke; 
        border: 1px solid gray; 
        border-radius: 4px;         
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: none;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var svg_co2_emission = d3.select("#svg_co2_emission"),
    margin_co2_emission = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width_co2_emission = +svg_co2_emission.attr("width") - margin_co2_emission.left - margin_co2_emission.right,
    height_co2_emission = +svg_co2_emission.attr("height") - margin_co2_emission.top - margin_co2_emission.bottom,
    g_co2_emission = svg_co2_emission.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_co2_emission.left + "," + margin_world_population.top + ")");

var x_co2_emission = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width_co2_emission])
    .padding(0.1)
    .align(0.1);
var y_co2_emission = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height_co2_emission, 0]);

var line_co2_emission = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x_co2_emission(+d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y_co2_emission(+d.total_emission); });

// Tooltip
var tt_co2_emission = d3.select("#svg_co2_emission").append("div")  
    .attr("class", "tooltip")       
    .style("opacity", 0);

d3.csv("t2_carbon_emission.csv", type, function(error, data_co2_emission) {
  if (error) throw error;
  x_co2_emission.domain(data_co2_emission.map(function(d) { return +d.year; }));
  y_co2_emission.domain([0, d3.max(data_co2_emission, function(d) { return +d.total_emission; })]).nice();

  g_co2_emission.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height_co2_emission + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x_co2_emission))
      .selectAll("text")  
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                  .attr("dy", ".15em")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );;
  g_co2_emission.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y_co2_emission).ticks(10, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y_co2_emission(y_co2_emission.ticks(10).pop()))
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("CO2: Million Metric Tons of Carbon Per Year.");

  g_co2_emission.append("path")
      .datum(data_co2_emission)
      .attr("class", "line_world_population")
      .attr("d", line_co2_emission);

  // Tooltip
  g_co2_emission.on("mousemove", function(d) {
    tt_co2_emission.html("&nbspIn " + x_co2_emission + ", CO2 Emission was <strong>" + y_co2_emission + "Million Metric Tons</strong>.&nbsp")
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 12 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 25 + 'px')
      .style("opacity", 0.95);
  });

  g_co2_emission.on("mouseout", function() {
    tt_co2_emission.style("opacity", 0)
  });
});
function type(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}
});
```

It is currently showing me an error message `d.year doesn't exist`. But If I make a change, it will not display an error and still no tooltip.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: can you create a working example? (jsfiddle/snippet)

Comment: never done that, let me give it a try.

Comment: How to add my data file to jsfiddle any clue?

Comment: you can just add the data as a javascript variable inside the jsfiddle javascript block.

Comment: Don't bother creating the fiddle, it's not necessary, the problem is evident: there is no data bound to `g_co2_emission`. The best idea now is looking for some tutorials about how to retrieve the y value of a line based on the x mouse value.

Comment: @Dekel apologies, unable to set up Fiddle, seems I have to make lot of changes to get that done. If there is any other site where I can upload my csv file as well, it will be nice.

Comment: Why are you using $(document).ready(function() { from what I understand this is unnecessary? And it is hard to know what is happening without t2_carbon_emission.csv or even a section of it. also what libraries are you using and version numbers.

Comment: Yeah, it was part of tweaking @theWhiteFox. It is not necessary I know... But just want to give it a try, my bad :D

Comment: Implemented x_co2_emission.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]) to get x and y coordinates but that gave me an error message: x_co2_emission.invert is not a function. Any clue?

Comment: There is no `invert` for an ordinal scale. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573630/how-can-i-implement-an-invert-function-for-a-point-scale/40574104#40574104

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado, thanks for your reply. Let me quickly check. I have one more question which I've posted few days back but didn't get any response. It is related to choropleth map inspired by your blog. If you wish you can have a look at that question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591970/d3-choropleth-map-colors-are-not-appearing